# How to fix weka error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, weka

When I tried to launch `weka 3.8.6`.

It didn't launch but pops up `Weka Error`.
When I tried to run `weka 3.8.6` the Error is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: How are you launching Weka? On what operating system (Linux/Mac/Windows)? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.